# XPath - preceding sibling contains an element check

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following simplified HTML from a webpage...

```
<div class="row import-entity">
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span class="mandatory"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="ImportTemplateEntities_2918.Header" type="hidden"></input>
                <input id="ImportTemplateEntities_5923.Header"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="ImportTemplateEntities_1234.Column"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="ImportTemplateEntities_9182.Header" type="hidden"></input>
                <input id="ImportTemplateEntities_2834.Header"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="ImportTemplateEntities_1243.Column"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With a requirement for the following XPath selection criteria...

- An **input** tag that is within a **col-md-3** **div** that is immediately after a **col-md-3** **div** that contains a **span** with class = mandatory
- **input** tag shouldn't be hidden

The following element from the HTML above matches the search criteria

```
<input id="ImportTemplateEntities_5923.Header"></input>
```

(Note that the numerical value in the ID is assigned dynamically, and won't be known to me when searching the document.)

Before adding any sort of preceding sibling check this is what I have....

```
//input[contains(@id,'ImportTemplateEntities')][contains(@id,'Header')][not(contains(@type,'hidden'))]
```

How would I edit this to add a condition for checking whether the preceding sibling `div` contains a `span` with `class` = `mandatory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//input[contains(@id,'ImportTemplateEntities')]
       [contains(@id,'Header')]
       [not(@type='hidden')]
       [../preceding-sibling::div[span/@class='mandatory']]
```

will select all `input` elements whose `id` attribute value contains the noted substrings *and* does not have a `type` attribute whose value is `hidden` *and* whose parent has a preceding sibling `div` element with a child `span` that has a `class` attribute with a value of `mandatory`, as requested.